# Playing multiple MP3 songs simultaneously on iPhone

Tags: iphone, mp3, core-audio, mixing

I would like to do a mixing table on iPhone. I have the different tracks of one song and I want to play them on iPhone simultaneously. These songs are MP3 files, I want to be able to play up to 15 tracks simultaneously, and changing volume, muting some tracks, navigating in the total song, etc.

Apple MultichannelMixer example seems to do exactly what I want, but MP3 files need to be decompressed before being played. They seem to be decompressed to CAF files, and take a lot of space in memory (my songs can last up to 5 minutes).

I tried SpeakHere example too, and use AudioQueue. I tried it with playing 6 AudioQueues simultaneously. It seems to work on the simulator, but I don't know if it will work on the device, and if it can do what I want.

I don't know what is the best way to do this... Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

look at here. Apple suggest this:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/codinghowtos/AudioAndVideo/#PLAYBACK-PLAY_MULTIPLE_SOUNDS_SIMULTANEOUSLY

Comment: I saw it but I don't understand : it seems that it is possible to play one MP3 at time, but when I tried on the simulator, I created one AudioQueue per track, and they are all played...

Is the behaviour different between the device and the simulator ?

Using this method, should the tracks being really synchronous ? It is the most important point of my application.

Thanks a lot for your answer Hasan !